# Bokeh: Add annotations/glyphs from server callback

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to add annotations from a server callback. The callback should "wrap" a tapped point with a region on its sides.

My code looks like the following:

```py
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import BoxAnnotation
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.plotting import figure


def _app(doc):
    p = figure(tools=['tap'])

    x = np.random.random(size=1000) - .5
    x_cum = np.cumsum(x)
    t = np.arange(len(x))

    s = p.scatter(t, x_cum)

    def handler(attr, old, new):
        print('attr: {} old: {} new: {}'.format(attr, old, new))

        new_layout = []

        for t in new:
            new_layout.append(BoxAnnotation(left=t - 5, right=t + 5, fill_color='green', fill_alpha=.3, level='underlay'))

        p.center = new_layout


    s.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', handler)

    doc.add_root(p)


server = Server({'/': _app}, num_procs=1)
server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```

I also tried `p.add_layout` instead of setting `p.center` but nothing. I saw that for Jupyter notebooks there's the `push_notebook()` function that might've worked here, so maybe something similar for a server will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails with an exception before it even has a chance of setting that callback. You should've received the `RuntimeError: Columns need to be 1D (y is not)` error. To fix it, replace

```py
x = np.random.random(size=(1, 1000)) - .5
x_cum = np.cumsum(x, axis=1)
```

with

```py
x = np.random.random(size=(1000,)) - .5
x_cum = np.cumsum(x)
```

And definitely use `add_layout` instead of overwriting the whole `center` property because the latter will remove other things there, like grid lines.
Note that just calling `add_layout` over and over again will just add new annotations without removing the old ones. If you want to remove them, then you can directly set the `center` property, but use the old value filtered to exclude all `BoxAnnotation` instances.

Comment: I had to modify my code a bit, so that's why the exception occurs. For the other part, it doesn't matter. I want the boxes to show but they're not shown. When you run the code and tap on a scatter-point, does a box appear?

Comment: Your answer didn't help me directly. It has been helpful, howerver, in that that I realized that the code it might be working for you and not for me. I checked the version for the package I have, and it turns out I have version 2.0.1 where the latest is 2.3.dev1. I updated to the latest version, and it solved this.